# SwiftUI Observed Object not updating when published value changes

Tags: swift, mvvm, swiftui, view, observedobject

I was following along with [this lecture](https://youtu.be/oWZOFSYS5GE) when I ran into some problems with my Observed Object updating. I have an `@ObservedObject` called `EmojiMemoryGame` with a published `MemoryGame<String>` variable called `model`. 'MemoryGame' is a struct that stores an array of cards, which each have a `Bool` variable that stores whether they are face up or not.

My `ContentView` is a View that shows each card in a grid on screen. When the user taps the card, `viewModel.choose(card)` toggles the `isFaceUp` variable of the card; the problem is that this does not cause the card to flip over on screen. This is my code in `ContentView.swift`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: EmojiMemoryGame
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 89))]) {
                ForEach(viewModel.cards) { card in
                    CardView(card: card)
                        .aspectRatio(2/3, contentMode: .fit)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            viewModel.choose(card)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(.red)
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}

struct CardView: View {
    let card: MemoryGame<String>.Card
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            
            if card.isFaceUp {
                shape
                    .fill()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                shape
                    .strokeBorder(lineWidth: 3)
                Text(card.content)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
            } else {
                shape
                    .fill()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the code works as expected if I instead just copy/paste the code from `CardView` directly into the body of `ContentView` (see below), so I'm not really sure what is going on here.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: EmojiMemoryGame
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 89))]) {
                ForEach(viewModel.cards) { card in
                    ZStack {
                        let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                        
                        if card.isFaceUp {
                            shape
                                .fill()
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                            shape
                                .strokeBorder(lineWidth: 3)
                            Text(card.content)
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                        } else {
                            shape
                                .fill()
                        }
                    }
                    .aspectRatio(2/3, contentMode: .fit)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        viewModel.choose(card)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(.red)
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

Edit: Here is my `EmojiMemoryGame.swift`:

```swift
class EmojiMemoryGame: ObservableObject {
    static let emojis = ["", "", "‍️", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "‍", "", "", "", ""]
    
    static func createMemoryGame() -> MemoryGame<String> {
        MemoryGame<String>(numberOfPairsOfCards: 4) { pairIndex in
            emojis[pairIndex]
        }
    }

    @Published var model: MemoryGame<String> = createMemoryGame()

    var cards: Array<MemoryGame<String>.Card> {
        return model.cards
    }
    
    func choose(_ card: MemoryGame<String>.Card) {
        model.choose(card)
    }
}
```

and `MemoryGame.swift`:

```swift
struct MemoryGame<CardContent> where CardContent: Equatable {
    
    struct Card: Identifiable, Equatable {
        var isFaceUp: Bool = false
        var isMatched: Bool = false
        var content: CardContent
        
        var id: Int
        
        static func == (lhs: MemoryGame<CardContent>.Card, rhs: MemoryGame<CardContent>.Card) -> Bool {
            lhs.id == rhs.id
        }
        
    }
    
    private(set) var cards: Array<Card>
        
    init(numberOfPairsOfCards: Int, createCardContent: (Int) -> CardContent) {
        cards = Array<Card>()
        // add numberOfPairsOfCards * 2 cards to cards array
        for pairIndex in 0..<numberOfPairsOfCards {
            let content: CardContent = createCardContent(pairIndex)
            cards.append(Card(content: content, id: pairIndex*2))
            cards.append(Card(content: content, id: pairIndex*2 + 1))
        }
    }
    
    mutating func choose(_ card: Card) {
        let chosenIndex = cards.firstIndex(of: card)
        cards[chosenIndex!].isFaceUp.toggle()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Did you try using `@StateObject` when first initializing `EmojiMemoryGame`?

Comment: Need code where you have @Published and model init

Comment: @BenMyers yes, unfortunately I'm still running into the same problem :/

Comment: Is it possible to add the .onTapGesture to your CardView? For example, at the bottom of your ZStack in your card view, add the onTapGesture. From my experience, onTapGesture does not seem to play nicely with For loops.

Comment: You need to change MemoryGame to class and make isFaceUp published. You don't have a publisher set up to propagate the change.

Comment: @nickreps I tried adding the .onTapGesture to my CardView but unfortunately this did not fix it

Comment: @cora I tried making MemoryGame and Card classes and publishing isFaceUp but it's still not working. I think the problem is probably something in my ContentView.swift file because my code works when I get rid of the CardView struct and paste the contents into ContentView directly.

Comment: If I copy the code above into Xcode, will it work? Or are there missing pieces needed to get it running on my end? If easier, you can upload to GitHub and I can clone and help diagnose!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ForEach` does not detect that any of cards changes because it is uses `Equatable` which in your case uses only `id`.

Here is a fix:

```
struct Card: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var isFaceUp: Bool = false
    var isMatched: Bool = false
    var content: CardContent

    var id: Int

    static func == (lhs: MemoryGame<CardContent>.Card, rhs: MemoryGame<CardContent>.Card) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.isFaceUp == rhs.isFaceUp   // << here !!
    }
}
```

and also needed update for

```
mutating func choose(_ card: Card) {
    let chosenIndex = cards.firstIndex{ $0.id == card.id } // << here !!
    cards[chosenIndex!].isFaceUp.toggle()
}
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5